# Can't connect as admin with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've a CentOS 5 Plesk server.

I have an updated version of phpMyAdmin in a public folder and if I try to login with my admin details (the root user of the entire MySQL server) everything works fine.

If I try to login with the same user using MySQL Workbench it says:

```
Failed to Connecto to MySQL at <myip>:3306 with user admin

Access denied for user
'admin'@'<myisphost>.fastwebnet.it' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried other users and they works if I use the old authentication protocol. So I've tried with this option but the error is the same.

Connecting to MySQL from SSH terminal everything works fine, looks like the problem is only with Workbench...
Any help?

Comment: do you have this error too ?? `Check the admin has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines`

Comment: In the popup error I've not this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First variant:**

Looks like your **admin** acount has been limited to access only from localhost.
Login to MySQL using `mysql` command from `ssh` (using your **root** credentials) and run this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'<myisphost>.fastwebnet.it' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This will allow you to connect from your host (**`<myisphost>.fastwebnet.it`**).

To check your access privileges:

```
 SHOW GRANTS;
```

If you'll have something like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'
```

than you have access only from **localhost** (machine where MySQL server is running on).

also you can check privileges using this command:

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
```

**Second variant:**

Second one variant is to use ssh-tunnel.

1. In **MySQL Workbench** when creating new connection select
   connection method as "Standart  TCP/IP over SSH" option.
2. Fill in your SSH/MySQL credintials. Please note to use your MySQL access options as for **localhost**.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I've not a static IP so I can't use your solution. How can I do? Maybe limit the access to *.fastwebnet.it... I don't know if is possible. Or maybe do something with SSH?

Comment: you can use next command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%.fastwebnet.it' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Also you can use SSH tunnel. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just closed all the current tabs in Workbench and logged in again.

Comment: yes. I also did the same

Comment: No need to do all the other steps.  Logging out of workbench and back in again did it for me also.  I put in my new password, and everything opened fine.  :-)